# Simple puppet module for Java8 for a VM built with Vagrant

Tags: java, java-8, vagrant, puppet, provisioning

I'm trying to write a puppet module to install Java 8 on a virtual machine.
With Java 6 it was not a problem: I wrote a java.pp with more or less these lines and everything worked correctly.

```
class java_6 {

package { "openjdk-6-jdk":
  ensure => installed,
require => Exec["update-package-list"],
}}
```

I tried with some tutorial online, but everything seems to be more complex than I need. Do you have some idea how to obtain Java 8 installed on VM through Puppet?

Answer (score 0):

**`java8.pp` for Ubuntu:**

```
case $::operatingsystem {
    ubuntu: {
      include apt

      apt::ppa { 'ppa:openjdk-r/ppa': 
        ensure => present,
      }

      exec { 'apt-update':
        command => '/usr/bin/apt-get update',
        require => [
          Apt::Ppa['ppa:openjdk-r/ppa']
        ],
      }

      package { 'openjdk-8-jdk':
        require  => [
          Exec['apt-update'],
          Apt::Ppa['ppa:openjdk-r/ppa'],
        ],
      }
    }

    default: {
      notice "Unsupported operatingsystem ${::operatingsystem}"
    }
  }
```

This java8.pp file depends on apt module, which has to be installed on your machine.

1. `sudo puppet module install puppetlabs-apt`
2. `sudo puppet apply java8.pp`
3. Running `java -version` to verify:

   ravitezu@Lenevo:~/Workspace/Puppet$ java -version
   openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need to build a module yourself to have Java8 running, most recommended ways is to let master do it and use modules like the [puppetlabs-java](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/java) puppet module, latest update can install Java 8 with simple class

```
class { 'java' : 
  distribution  => 'jdk',
  package       => 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
}
```

Comment: I haven't understood what do you mean. What should I declare into file init.pp, in java/manifest?

Comment: no you need to install the puppetlabs-java module (either pushing to puppet/modules or from install script) and then in your puppet file (can be init or something else) declared from Vagrantfile you will just reference this class - Here I proposed you not to create a new module but to use an existing one

Comment: Ok, thanks. So in my site.pp file I'll have something like
node 'web'{
class { 'java' : 
  distribution  => 'jdk',
  package       => 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
}}
I have another question now: if I have to install many sw (java, postgres,...) my site.pp will grow a lot. Is this the right way to proceed? Or is there some "pattern" to adopt?

Comment: If you feel your files is getting too big, you can break it down and make sure to include the other class when needed from the other puppet file